# Limit Superior and Limit Inferior of a Countable Family of Sets

Tags: general-topology, set-theory

If $\left\{E_{n}\right\}$ is a family of sets indexed by $\mathbb{N}$, then

\begin{equation*}
\mbox{lim sup}\,E_{n} = \bigcap_{k=1}^{\infty}{\bigcup_{n=k}^{\infty}{E_{n}}}
\end{equation*}

and

\begin{equation*}
\mbox{lim inf}\,E_{n} = \bigcup_{k=1}^{\infty}{\bigcap_{n=k}^{\infty}{E_{n}}}
\end{equation*}

According to Folland (*Real Analysis*, 2nd edition)

\begin{equation*}
\mbox{lim sup}\,E_{n} = \left\{x~;~x\in E_{n}\mbox{ for infinitely many }n\right\}
\end{equation*}

and

\begin{equation*}
\mbox{lim inf}\,E_{n} = \left\{x~;~x\in E_{n}\mbox{ for all but finitely many }n\right\}.
\end{equation*}

I'm wondering how to show that this is the case.

We have that $x\in \mbox{lim sup}\,E_{n}$  if and only if $x\in \bigcup_{n=k}^{\infty}{E_{n}}$ for all $k$. But how do I proceed from here? I guess the thing to do is to show that $x\in \mbox{lim sup}\,E_{n}$ if and only if $|\mathbb{N}| = |\mathbb{N}\setminus\left\{k~;~x\not\in E_{k}\right\}|$, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Folland's definition deals with countable families of sets $E_n$. These sets are completely arbitrary, they need not be subsets of $\mathbb R$. Thus one must not confuse $\limsup E_n$ and  $\liminf E_n$ with the usual definition of $\limsup x_n$ and $\liminf x_n$ for real sequences $(x_n)$ (see Folland p. 11).

As you say, we have that $x\in \mbox{lim sup}\,E_{n}$  if and only if $x\in \bigcup_{n=k}^{\infty}{E_{n}}$ for all $k$. The latter is true if and only if $x \in E_n$ for infinitely many $n$:

If $x \in E_n$ for infinitely many $n =n_1, n_2, n_3,\ldots$ with $n_i < n_{i+1}$, then each $\bigcup_{n=k}^{\infty}{E_{n}}$ contains $x$ because for each $k$ there is $n_i$ with $n_i \ge k$.

If $x \in E_n$ only for finitely many $n =n_1, n_2, n_3,\ldots,n_r$ with $n_i < n_{i+1}$, then $\bigcup_{n=n_r+1}^{\infty}{E_{n}}$ does not contain $x$.

Similarly we have that $x\in \mbox{lim inf}\,E_{n}$  if and only if $x\in \bigcap_{n=k}^{\infty}{E_{n}}$ for some $k$. The latter is true if and only if $x \in E_n$ for all but finitely many $n$:

If $x \notin E_n$ only for finitely many $n =n_1, n_2, n_3,\ldots,n_r$ with $n_i < n_{i+1}$, then $x \in \bigcap_{n=n_r+1}^{\infty}{E_{n}}$.

If $x \notin E_n$ for infinitely many $n =n_1, n_2, n_3,\ldots$ with $n_i < n_{i+1}$, then no $\bigcap_{n=k}^{\infty}{E_{n}}$ contains $x$ because for each $k$ there is $n_i$ with $n_i \ge k$.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by noting that $x\in A$ if and only if $\mathbf{1}_A(x)=1$, where $\mathbf{1}_A$ is the indicator function.

This way you can see that

$$ \mbox{lim sup}\,E_{n} =\{ x: \limsup \mathbf{1}_{E_n}(x)=1 \} \quad \text{and} \quad \mbox{lim inf}\,E_{n} =\{ x: \liminf \mathbf{1}_{E_n}(x)=1 \}, $$

since $\mathbf{1}_{E_n}$ only takes values of $1$ or $0$.

For a sequence $\{a_n\}_{n=1}^\infty$, $\limsup a_n=1$ if and only if $a_n=1$ for infintely many $n$'s. Likewise,, for such a sequence, $\liminf a_n=1$ if and only if $a_n=1$ for all but finitely many $n$'s.

You can also check set inequalities, but I think this is a very neat and useful observation.